# Timeline cursor

Tags: shortcut

I'm new to blender trying to learn the viewport and the hotkeys. Every time I press the spacebar the timeline cursor starts to move obviously. A lot of hotkeys are linked to the spacebar. How do I get the timeline cursor not to start but still have the spacebar as a hotkey for the play button when I need to use the animation.

Comment: Go to page 4 in scrapbook link here. There, you will find what I consider the best playlists of 2.8x tutorials for absolute beginners like yourself. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs

Comment: Hi. What do you mean "A lot of hotkeys are linked to the spacebar"? Also, please make the title of the question specific to what you're asking and not just the general topic.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly question. Coming from another program I was pressing the spacebar inadvertently and obviously the timeline cursor was starting to move. No, spacebar is not linked as a hotkey to other commands, but the play/start one in timeline. Hopefully other starters who run into the same problem read this and control their thumb :-) Old habits die hard. Thank you for taking the time to answer me.